# Bootstrap - ASP.NET Core

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I would like to ask how I can stretch the width throughout the modal form.

Here is my code:

```
<form asp-controller="Employee" asp-action="Create" method="post" class="form-inline" role="form">
<div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Create New Employee</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="hidden" id="Id">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="vertical-align:middle;margin-top: -5px"></span> Create</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and it shows like this:

[input text problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nF6Z4.png)

Is there any way that I could fix this problem.

I think it has something to do with the bootstrap library but I don't know where it is located.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form asp-controller="Employee" asp-action="Create" method="post" class="form-inline" role="form">
<div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Create New Employee</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="hidden" id="Id">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="vertical-align:middle;margin-top: -5px"></span> Create</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/0fscmf3L/

Credits: Kyle Mitofsky

Comment: that's why I put his jsfiddle link

Comment: It is always good to include credits otherwise you might get downvoted, so added it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use bootstrap grid system.

```css
#inpt {
width: 100%;
}
.modal-body {
height: 200px;}
```

```html
<form asp-controller="Employee" asp-action="Create" method="post" class="form-inline" role="form">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">button</a>
<div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Create New Employee</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div  class="form-group col-xs-12">
                    <input id="inpt" type="text" class="form-control"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="hidden" id="Id">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="vertical-align:middle;margin-top: -5px"></span> Create</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```